# I have issue when using Visual studio to generate sabre proxy for EnhancedAirBook3.9

Tags: .net, sabre

I'm working on upgrading EnhancedAirBook to V3.9, and got wsdl file in Sabre support site.

But when I tried using Visual studo tool to generate proxy:
wsdl http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/ServicesPlatform/EnhancedAirBook3.9.0RQ.wsdl

I'm having following error:

*Schema validation error: Schema with targetNamespace='http://service.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_9' has invalid syntax. Undefined complexType 'http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01:STL_Response_Payload' is used as a base for complex type extension. Line 15, position 18.
Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.*

I'm using VS 8.0 wsdl(I didn't find newer version has the tool).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Harrison

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide other xsd's that your wsdl need. You can find all other helper .xsd files on developer.sabre.com.

When I want to generate classes from sabre wsdl, I use those .xsd files below:

[image]

Comment: hello i am using readyapi tool to generate code.
i am getting same error in PassengerDetialsRQ.
other RQ Files Successfully Generated and its working fine.